# Writing data over TCP using CocoaAsyncSocket Library

Tags: ios, tcp

I've got the CocoaAsyncSocket Library happily connecting to a remote server and I'm wanting my code to also write data to that server. However, I'm finding with all the projects in the folder that I can't locate the code I need to be able to do this.

Can someone please either:

- point me to the project / file / method I need to look at in order to get my app to write data to the connect server over tcp?
- please just tell me the code I need to write?

Comment: Not sure understanding what you were saying?  re-read your question and see if you can make it clearer.

Comment: sorry man, long day. Edited now